# How do you deploy Nodejs using Zeit now?

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my back-end `nodejs` server ising `now` by Zeit

I installed it using the `npm i -g now` command
and I used the `now` command to deploy, but I'm getting this error:

```
Now CLI 17.1.1
Error! The content of "~\AppData\Roaming\now\Data\auth.json" is invalid. No `token` property found inside. Run `now login` to authorize.
```

I'm confused on what I did wrong, any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I had to run the command:

`now login`

then it asks for my Zeit account info. Afterwards, I navigated to the directory where my server files are and used the command:

`now`

to innitiate and deploy the backend.
Once it was done, it gave me a URL which I can use to access the backend within my front-end code